# How to resolve desugaring error with Android Studio

Tags: android, itext7, androidx

I encountered an error when I tried to run an app using the Itext7.

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\IbisAmeer\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\io-7.1.3.jar\580a305969b6598df0e241c92902de8d\jetified-io-7.1.3.jar
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)
```

Then I decided to look deeper into the Gradle logs and I got tons of this warning

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Type org.slf4j.LoggerFactory was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of byte[] com.itextpdf.io.font.Type1Font.getFontStreamBytes()`","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\IbisAmeer\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-1\\files-1.1\\io-7.1.3.jar\\580a305969b6598df0e241c92902de8d\\jetified-io-7.1.3.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}
```

I'm using Android 3.2

Answer (score 1):

I assume, you have all the required dependencies in your build.gradle file.

Based on no problem with dependencies. Another problem could be with gradle if you are using Java 9/10/11. Please migrate to use the latest gradle 10.1 / 10.2. It could be there due to Java 9 module feature.

If you still face issue then please share the sample code.